# How to set default filter to hide div

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="#" data-category-type="high">high</a>

<a href="#" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="air">low</a>

<a href="#" data-category-name="pizza">pizza</a>

</div>
<div id="Categories">
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pizza">high</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pasta">low</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pizza">low</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pasta">high</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cat = $(this).data('categoryType');
    var nam = $(this).data('categoryName');
    $('#Categories > div').hide();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').show();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').show();

});
```

By default, i want to show only the div with type "high"
Can someone pls tell me how to set the default state instead of showing all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide all divs within categories and show the ones with `type = "high"`

```js
$('#Categories > div').hide();
$('#Categories > div[data-category-type="high"]').show();

$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cat = $(this).data('categoryType');
    var nam = $(this).data('categoryName');
    $('#Categories > div').hide();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').show();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
<a href="#" data-category-type="high">high</a>

<a href="#" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="air">low</a>

<a href="#" data-category-name="pizza">pizza</a>

</div>
<div id="Categories">
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pizza">high</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pasta">low</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pizza">low</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pasta">high</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try, I just added condition to check if its high

```
  $('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cat = $(this).data('categoryType');
    var nam = $(this).data('categoryName');
    $('#Categories > div').hide();
    if(cat=="high"){
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').show();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').show();
  }else{
       $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').hide();
      $('#Categories > div[data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').hide();

   }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

1. set the style="display:none" for the divs you don't want to show.
2. Hide the divs inside $(document).ready.

Use either html or javascript mentioned below.

```js
$('#Categories > div[data-category-type=low]').hide();
$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cat = $(this).data('categoryType');
    var nam = $(this).data('categoryName');
    $('#Categories > div').hide();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').show();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
<a href="#" data-category-type="high">high</a>

<a href="#" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="air">low</a>

<a href="#" data-category-name="pizza">pizza</a>

</div>
<div id="Categories">
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pizza">high</div>
    <div class="hide" style="display:none" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pasta">low</div>
    <div class="hide" style="display:none" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pizza">low</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pasta">high</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide div's using CSS-style, like this:

```
<div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pizza">high</div>
<div style="display: none" class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pasta">low</div>
<div style="display: none" class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pizza">low</div>
<div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pasta">high</div>
```